# Is it bad to store $_session variables for every user?

Tags: php

Question basically says it all. I get a lot of traffic, about 200k hits a day. I want to store the original referrer (where they came from) in a session variable for various purposes. Is this a good idea or should I stick in a database instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both at once :). PHP allows you define the storage logic of your sessions in scripts. This way it is possible to store sessions in a database as well. Check the manual of [`set_session_save_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

Using a database would have its advantages if you use load balancing (or plan to do it once). This way all web servers could read the session data from the same database (or cluster) and the load balancer would not have to worry about which request should be forwarded to which web server. If session data is stored in files, which is the default mechanism, then a load balancer has to forwared each request of a session to the same physical web server, which is much more complex, as the load balancer has to work on HTTP level.

Answer (score 1):

You could just store the information in a cookie if you only need it for the user's current session. Then you don't need to store it at all on your end.

There are a few down sides as well:

1. They may have cookies disabled, so you may not be able to save it.
2. If you need the information next time you may not be able to get it, as it could have been deleted.
3. Not super secure so don't save passwords, bank info, etc.

So if needing this information is required no matter what, maybe its not the way to go. If the information is optional, then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The default PHP session handler is the file handler. So, the pertinent questions are:

1. Are you using more than 1 webserver without sticky sessions (load balancing)?
2. Are you running out of disk space?
3. Do you ever intend to do those?

If yes (to any), then store it in a database. Or, even better, calculate the stuff on every request (or cache it somewhere like Memcached). You could also store the stuff in a signed cookie (to prevent tampering).